# How to organize Pusher JS Library in the client side to bind to several channels and listen to several events?

Tags: php, laravel, real-time, pusher

I'm using Pusher to broadcast my Laravel Events, however I'm facing a doubt:

If I have a channel, let's name it `global_updates` which I would like to use to send global updates like news or site status so I just do:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('#################', {
        encrypted: true
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('global_updates');
    channel.bind('global_event', function(data) {
        // stuff
    });
```

So, until here everything goes fine, but what if I would like to consume several events for the same channel? How can I manage it? Should I do:

```
var pusher = new Pusher('#################', {
        encrypted: true
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('global_updates');
    channel.bind('global_event', function(data) {
        // stuff
    });

    channel.bind('global_event2', function(data) {
        // stuff for other event
    });

    channel.bind('global_event3', function(data) {
        // stuff for the 3rd event
    });
```

Is that a good approach? Now, what if I would like to send peruser messages along with the global, let's say there is a channel per user named `user_(user_id)` but I still want to consume the global events. Should I subscribe to both at the same time?

```
var pusher = new Pusher('#################', {
        encrypted: true
    });
    var channel = pusher.subscribe('global_updates');
    var UserChannel = pusher.subscribe('user_(user_id)');

    channel.bind('global_event', function(data) {
        // stuff
    });

    UserChannel.bind('per_user_event', function(data) {
        // stuff
    });
```

The thing is I could then have like 100s of subscribed users but not unique users, since each one could be subscribed to several channels, even when they are not consuming messages.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr: your approach is sound.

A client can subscribe to as many channels as they like - there are no restrictions. The only time there is any significant overheard would be when subscribing to 100s of channels or subscribing to many [private channels](https://pusher.com/docs/private_channels) where each subscription will result in an [authentication call](https://pusher.com/docs/authenticating_users) (however this can be batched).

From a "good practice" point of view I would recommend having one channel for global events received by all users and each user should have their own channel upon which events are sent that should *only* be received by that user. For security purposes I'd recommend the user channel to be a private channel. If you are using Event Broadcasting within Laravel you'll need to implement an authentication endpoint and that will require setting up the [Pusher Laravel Bridge](https://github.com/vinkla/pusher).

I'd recommend the [Building Real-Time Laravel Apps with Pusher](https://pusher-community.github.io/real-time-laravel/) (which I wrote - I work for Pusher).